# Не могу подключить к postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate

Возникает ошибка `Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'` при работе со Spring.

Настройки базы данных:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
    ds.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
    ds.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
    ds.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

    ds.setInitialSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.initialSize")));
    ds.setMinIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.minIdle")));
    ds.setMaxIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.maxIdle")));
    ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(Long.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis")));
    ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(Long.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis")));
    ds.setTestOnBorrow(Boolean.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.testOnBorrow")));
    ds.setValidationQuery(env.getRequiredProperty("db.validationQuery"));

    return ds;
}
```

В свойствах указано `db.driver = org.postgresql.Driver`. Что может быть не так с драйвером ?

Comment: JAR с драйвером-то лежит в CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы java могла создать объект класса `org.postgresql.Driver`, jar-файл драйвера (например, `postgresql-9.4.1209.jar`), в котором объявлен этот класс, должен лежать в [CLASSPATH](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-classpath-windows/).

Скорее всего, в вашей IDE (вы же не пишете spring-приложение в блокноте?) можно подключать библиотеки в проект, указав пути к jar-файлам. Драйвер postgresql можно скачать отсюда:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Также у веб-сервера (например, Apache Tomcat) обычно есть папка lib, куда можно положить jar-файл драйвера для использования приложениями